# Running database TDD tests

Tags: php, database, tdd

I'm using TDD (Test Driven Development) with my PHP project and I also have a database where I store things like users.
I have a class which creates a user, so it's something similar to:

```
$user = new User();
$user->create('username', 'password', 'mail');
```

So, I also have a test that tests if that method (create a user) works. So, my problem is that every time I run the test, a user is created, so it works.
But I was wondering if there's a way to do the test and not to create information in my database, because everytime I run all my tests, it creates new users so I have my database full of users created with the tests.

Hope you understand me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to add with your Create Test a Delete Test. After your test creates the new User you would turn around and delete it back out of the DB. That way you are testing 2 things at once and not polluting your DB and if either fails you will know.

Another approach would be to abstract away your DB calls so that you can have something in memory pretend to be the DB when you create a new user, or make any other DB calls.

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing what you said in the first paragraph! But I didn't truly understand what you said on the second paragraph... Are you suggesting to create another db for the tests? Thanks!!

Comment: No it wouldn't be creating another DB. I guess the second method wouldn't actually tell you if the User was saved. I think deleting the user after creating it would likely be the best way to start out.

Comment: Another thought. Could you setup a transaction to the DB before you create the User and then save the User inside of that transaction, and if the Insert works inside of the transaction you can rollback the transaction. That way you would know that the insert worked, and would not have commmited the record to the DB.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand you... Do you mean doing the transaction as if it was normal, and then do a rollback? I found this, which I suppose that is what you told me, isn't it? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-transactions.htm